# POST data and redirect through Deeplink in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post

I need to send data with POST which has custom controlled fields and user should be redirected to another page with the relevant data sent.

Usually, for GET requests Deeplink URL can be dynamically updated as in :

```
handleRedirect=()=>{
 let url = "booking.testurl.com/test?lang={BOOLEAN}&name={NAME}"
```

and then,

```
 window.location.href = url; 
}
```

redirects to subsequent page with results.

What is the best cross browser implementation for the same if I need to use POST (required by subsequent URL) and then redirect?

p.s.: Not all fields are vanilla input fields, so I don't want to go`<Form method=POST> way`

Update:

The get deeplinking url will look like:

`https://booking.testurl.com/test?lang=EN&name=NAME`

For Post:

```
https://mbooking.testurl.com/test
body:{
      lang: "EN",
      Name: "NAME"
 }
```

Form page is : `"https://testurl.com"`

As mentioned, there won't be any response from these urls, it would just be redirection on submit, but with post

Answer (score 1):

Use either the [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) API, which has become pretty standard on all the later versions of chrome/firefox, or use some library such as [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to make the post request using standard ajax.

[`await`](https://javascript.info/async-await) or attach a callback (`.then()`) to the promise that's returned, which upon completion, you can use `window.location.href = url;` to direct them to another url. If this is a single page application, you can look into the relevant parts of react-router to do this as well (To avoid a full page refresh).

Comment: The url where data is POSTed is deeplinked and no response will be triggered. So fetch will end up with "could not redirect" error in .catch.

Comment: What do you mean by deeplinked. Can you update your question with an example of what is happening when you use the fetch API, along with the full error?